# What is the exact directional derivative for this function?(Non differentiable)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Say $f : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$. Find the directional derivative at the point $(0,0)$ for the $\vec v = (1,1)$

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{ysin^2x}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

For the unit-vector ,$\vec u =$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\vec v =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1,1) $

Hence $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f((0,0)+h\vec u)-f(0,0)}h =\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{h}{\sqrt2}sin^2(\frac{h}{\sqrt2})}{h^3} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

But the answer sheet claimed

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f((0,0)+h\vec v)-f(0,0)}h =\lim_{h\to0}\frac{hsin^2(h)}{2h^3} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Which one is correct? I'm very confused. Does the directional derivative exist?

Comment: It's up to the definition your book uses. Some authors say you have to use a unit vector, others take the vector as is: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

Comment: @Tyberius, Ah thanks for comment. Then, Are the both of them correct depending on the definition?

Comment: I believe there is correct assuming you just take the vector as is and your is correct if you use a definition that requires the vector be normalized.

Comment: @Tyberius You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to just be a matter of definition. You are using a form of the directional derivative that requires a unit vector (or equivalently dividing the derivative by the norm of the direction vector):

$$D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{x})=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h|\mathbf{v}|}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}$$

where $\mathbf{u}$ is the unit vector of $\mathbf{v}$ as in your post.

However, the more common definition just takes the vector as is:
$$D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{x})=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}$$

This is convenient because it allows us to use the directional derivative even for spaces where a norm (and hence unit vectors) is not defined. However, as long as you state your definition up front, there is nothing inherently wrong with the unit vector form.